# Bypassing the required fields on visualforce page & saving the record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a VF form of around 400 fields, in that the client requirement is, if the user chose to enter some of the fields & save the records, it should bypass the validation on the page & should save the records, the validation are done using JavaScript.
I need help in, how can I bypass the JavaScript validation & should save the record ?

Comment: If you dont need validation for few records then why have you put validations ?

Comment: The validation are mandatory for integration, but the client requirement is if the form is partially filled it should save it in another custom object & it should not do the integration, once the form is fully filled it should do the integration. The main concern is how to bypass the JavaScript validation.

Comment: assuming that it is a custom vf page which also has the javascript code that does the validation, can you just try updating the javascript code to not do the validation checks if certain fields are already populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, on submitting the form use immediate="true" with commandbutton and pass the value of every field explicitly using apex:param

One other approach is creating data in JSON format and then calling remote action and passing values.

Comment: Yes it worked, i tried with immediate="true" & was able to bypass the validation.

Comment: @TabrezAnsari But how did you manage to pass the values to the Server since `Immediate="True"` won't allow passing the value.